# SFML - sleep calculation

Tags: c++, audio, sleep, sfml

I am working on a benchmark application that would compare SFML and SDL. One of the things I'm benchmarking is speed of playing sound. I play the sound many times in a loop and calculate the time it takes. I need a delay between playing sounds since I first need to finish playing a sound to start over again. I fixed this with SFML sleep, however I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Probably not because after first play, the application freezes, like if it would be in an infinite loop. I need it to delay 1 millisecond if the music is still playing. Can you please help me out?

My functions:

```
void playSound()
{
    sound.setBuffer(buffer);
    sound.play();
}

void soundBenchmark(int numOfCycles)
{
    sf::Time delayTime = sf::milliseconds(0.01);
    sf::Clock clock;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfCycles; i++)
    {
        playSound();
        while(sound.Playing) sf::sleep(delayTime);
    }
    sf::Time time = clock.getElapsedTime();
    cout << "Time required for " << numOfCycles << " cycles playing sound: " <<  time.asMilliseconds() << " milliseconds.\n";
}
```

Calling the function in main:

```
while(running)
    {
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
                running = false;
            }
        }
        soundBenchmark(20);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "speed of playing sound"? I find the "benchmark" very odd and not sure if it would give you any useful information...

Also keep in mind that not processing events can lead to the OS believing that your application is frozen.

Comment: well, it takes some milliseconds for the library to process the information to play sound and actually play it. I want to play a sound many times on both libraries and then find out which one has lower time.

Comment: This makes no sense ? Playing a sound is definitely not an operation which would have an important (or even sensible) overhead in any use of a multimedia library. About `sf::Music`, it isn't read once but streamed from the disk so there's no point either.

Comment: One can discuss if it makes sense or not, but just checking by playing is not really representative, since playing a sound and its respond time can depend on many variables, from audio driver, over memory and motherboard layout. The main issue you'll run into with the current code is you sleep call, since your application will be "oversleeping", thus causing inaccurate numbers, not to forget that the sleep function isn't precise enough. You might want to just busy wait.

Comment: ok. Ill just skip this part of benchmark. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but just to point out the error on your code: the argument to the `sf::milliseconds()` function is the actual ammount of milliseconds, as a decimal value.

So, if you wanted it to wait 1ms, you should have entered `sf::milliseconds(1)`.

This behavior is valid in the current version (2.3 as of today), but I don't know if in previous versions it was different.